# Merge replication error the schema script could not be propagated to the subscriber SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I am with replication so after trying for 1 month I am able to initialize  publisher on remote system and subscriber on my local system. When I run job at subscriber end I get an error

> the schema script AccountNotic1234.sch could not be propagated to the subscriber

Somewhere I read this error happens when tables are connected using foreign keys and you missing primary table but I am synchronizing all tables. So it can not be the issue.

When I run the subscription I get error for 3 tables in order not on 1st and 2nd don't know why?

What can be the possible reasons for this?

Comment: Try enabling verbose agent logging.  It should tell you why the schema script could not be propagated to the subscriber.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312292  Use an -OutputVerboseLevel of 4 for the Merge Agent.